# Remover um elemento anterior ao elemento indicado pelo usuario em uma Lista. C

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Tenho que criar um programa, no qual, irá se criar uma lista dinâmica duplamente encadeada e esse programa deve fazer o seguinte:

o programa ira ler valores que o usuário escrever e adicionar à lista. Em seguida o usuário irá digitar um valor. O programa deve procurar esse valor na lista o excluir o elemento anterior a ele.

Por exemplo:

Na lista com os elementos {1, 2, 3, 4}, caso o usuário insira o código 3, o elemento 2 deve ser excluído. Eu sei que nesse caso, por exemplo, eu devo ligar o ponteiro "prox" do 1 ao 3 e o ponteiro "ant" do 3 ao 1, mas não estou conseguindo.

Caso o usuário digite o primeiro elemento ou algum que não esteja na lista aparecerá uma mensagem de erro(essa parte já implementei).

O problema é que não estou conseguindo apagar da lista o elemento anterior. Quando ponho para realizar essa função e depois imprimo a lista, o elemento ainda está lá.

Utilizei as seguintes estruturas:

```
typedef struct codigoProduto{
    int cod;
    struct codigoProduto *ant;
    struct codigoProduto *prox;
} produto;

typedef struct Lista{
    int tam;
    produto *inicio;
    produto *fim;
} lista;
```

E criei a função para remover o elemento anterior que ficou da seguinte forma:

```
void retiraAnterior(lista* LISTA, int indice){
    produto* tmp = LISTA->inicio;
    int vazio, achou;

    vazio = listaVazia(LISTA);
    if (vazio == 0){
        achou = busca(LISTA, indice);
        if (!achou){
            printf("Nao existe elemento solicitado na lista.\n Impossivel remover anterior.\n");
        }
        else{
            if (LISTA->inicio->cod == indice){
                printf("O elemento solicitado eh o primeiro da lista.\nImpossivel remover anterior.\n");
                return menu();
            }
            while(tmp->cod != indice){
                if (tmp->cod == indice){
                    tmp->ant->ant->prox = tmp;
                    tmp->ant = tmp->ant->ant;
                    LISTA->tam--;
                }
                tmp = tmp->prox;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A função vazio retorna 1 caso a lista esteja vazia e 0 caso contrário.
Enquanto a função busca retorna 1 caso ache o elemento na lista e 0 caso contrário.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver realizando as seguintes mudanças:

```
    void retiraAnterior(lista* LISTA, int indice){
        produto* tmp = LISTA->inicio;
        int vazio, achou;

        vazio = listaVazia(LISTA);
        if (vazio == 0){
            achou = busca(LISTA, indice);
            if (!achou){
                printf("Nao existe elemento solicitado na lista.\n Impossivel remover anterior.\n");
            }
            else{
                if (LISTA->inicio->cod == indice){
                    printf("O elemento solicitado eh o primeiro da lista.\nImpossivel remover anterior.\n");
                    return menu();
                }

                while(tmp->cod != indice){
                    tmp = tmp->prox;
                    //aux = tmp->ant;
                }
//tirei o if do loop e criei outra condição de borda pois estava dando erro sem ela.
                if (LISTA->tam == 2){
                    LISTA->inicio = tmp;
                    tmp->ant = NULL;
                }
                else{
                    tmp->ant->ant->prox = tmp;
                    tmp->ant = tmp->ant->ant;
                }

                LISTA->tam--;
                //free(aux);
            }
        }
    }
```